# How do I define "chkLongText_Checked"?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

This user interface has a short text and a long text option. When the long text is used, the buttons that contain the text are re-sized automatically. 
Here is what I have done, but I haven't the foggiest on how I am to define 'checkLongText_Unchecked.' It says I'm missing an extension method. Does anyone have any advice?

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HQy4.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phwe3.png)

```
<Window x:Class="Layout.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Button Name="cmdPrev" Margin="10,10,10,3">Prev</Button>
        <Button Name="cmdNext" Margin="10,3,10,3">Next</Button>
        <CheckBox Name="chkLongText" Margin="10,10,10,10"
         Checked="chkLongText_Checked" Unchecked="chkLongText_Unchecked">
         Show Long Text</CheckBox>
         </StackPanel>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,10,10"
             TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Grid.RowSpan="2"> This is a very basic test.</TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="cmdClose"
            Margin="10,3,10,10">Close</Button>
```

Here is the C#.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void chkLongText_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

    }
    private void chkLongText_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { }
}
```

The error is:

> Error 1   'Layout.MainWindow.chkLongText_Unchecked(object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)' must declare a body because it is not
>   marked abstract, extern, or partial   c:\users\kryssi\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\Layout\Layout\MainWindow.xaml.cs 33  22  Layout

Comment: Do you have a method `private void checkLongText_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { }` in your MainWindow.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind you need a method something like

```
private void checkLongText_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: It has this, @coagulantmonkey, but gives me the message:

Comment: Error 1 'Layout.MainWindow.chkLongText_Unchecked(object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial c:\users\kryssi\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Layout\Layout\MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: It seems like you have `private void checkLongText_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);` instead of `private void checkLongText_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { }`. According to this last error message you pasted.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi I did this and posted some updates above.